# gdb: A "continue" that doesn't interfer with "next" or "step"

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I'm currently debugging syslinux (a boot loader) through the gdb stub of qemu.

Recently, I wrote some gdb commands that (un)load the debug symbols everytime a module is dynamically (un)loaded. In order not to disrupt the execution, I ended the commands with `continue`.

```
break com32/lib/sys/module/elf_module.c:282
commands
    silent
    python
name = gdb.parse_and_eval("module->name").string()
addr = int(str(gdb.parse_and_eval("module->base_addr")), 0)
gdb.execute("load-syslinux-module %s 0x%08x" % (name, addr))
    end
    continue
end
```

However, when stepping through the code line by line, if the `next` or `step` command makes the execution hit the breakpoint, the breakpoints takes precedence, the commands are executed, including the `continue`. And the execution continue irrespectively of the line-by-line debugging I was doign. This also happen if I try to step over the function that has this breakpoint.

How can I keep (un)loading the debug symbols on the fly while not interfering with the debugging?

Is there an alternative to the `continue` command? Maybe using breakpoints isn't the right way? I'd take any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done from the gdb CLI.  However, it is easy to do from Python.

In Python the simplest way is to define one's own `gdb.Breakpoint` subclass, and define the `stop` method on it.  This method can do the work you like, then `return False` to tell gdb to continue.

The `stop` facility was designed to avoid the problems with `cont` in `commands`.  See [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html#Breakpoints-In-Python) for more details.

Comment: Can I make a hardware breakpoint with the class `gdb.Breakpoint`? I don't see any option for this. It turns out the software breakpoints don't always work.